# Get user name from its id..?

Tags: opentext, livelink

I have to communicate with OpenText LiveLink via its WCF interface.

I am using the `GetNode` function to which I pass a node ID and it returns information about the document.

One of the field returned is "CreatedBy": 797207

I would require to get a user name instead of an ID...How is that feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the  `getMemberByID` method of `MemberService` WS interface, whose XML request is the following:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:api.ecm.opentext.com" xmlns:urn1="urn:MemberService.service.livelink.opentext.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <urn:OTAuthentication>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:AuthenticationToken>?</urn:AuthenticationToken>
      </urn:OTAuthentication>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn1:GetMemberById>
         <urn1:memberID>?</urn1:memberID>
      </urn1:GetMemberById>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

In general MemberService (available at http://your-OTCS-server/cws/MemberService.svc) provides you a lot of other user-related functions:

[image: MemberService's available methods]

You can easily import the WSDL into, say, applications like SoapUI and perform all the testing you may need.

Comment: wow thanks! I never thought I would get an answer on that obscure technology :) I cannot find any documentation so I have to explore and deduce...thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. It's the magic of StackOverflow... :)) Pleased to help you.